How to batch multiple calls through a single function?
I have a smart contract that implements monolithic functions. These functions are designed to do one job when called by a user. However, a user may be interested in batching multiple calls into a single transaction. To achieve that, I could think of two solutions:

Define a separate periphery smart contract. The problem with this approach is I will have to maintain two separate contracts.
Implements those batch functions in the same smart contract. This is not scalable as there are multiple combinations possible. This would also increase the contract size.
Delegate call through proxy. The risk here is that if the core contract is BUSL licensed, anybody can deploy a proxy and use the logic from the core contract. So my contract does now allow delegate call from an external contract.

Are there any better solutions that can help me batch multiple calls through a single function so that it can be used to batch any arbitrary number of calls instead of defining them one by one?

Yes. It is entirely possible to batch multiple calls into a single without relying on external delegatecall. There are two similar implementations that you can use:

Boring Batchable: source code ↗

function batch(bytes[] calldata calls, bool revertOnFail) external payable {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < calls.length; ++i) {
        (bool success, bytes memory result) = address(this).delegatecall(calls[i]);
        if (!success && revertOnFail) {
            _getRevertMsg(result);
        }
    }
}

Since its added to the same contract, delegatecall is safe.

Multicall3: source code ↗

function aggregate(Call[] calldata calls) public payable returns (bytes[] memory returnData) {
    uint256 length = calls.length;
    returnData = new bytes[](length);
    Call calldata call;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        bool success;
        call = calls[i];
        (success, returnData[i]) = address(this).delegatecall(call.callData);
        require(success, "Multicall3: call failed");
    }
}

This implementation uses struct to organize call data as well as restun data.
I hope this answers your question. Good luck with your implementation.
